# How can I determine why onFailure is triggered in GWT-RPC?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I have a project that does 2 RPC calls and then saves the data that the user provided in tha datastore. The first RPC call works ok, but from the second I always recieve the `onFailure()` message. How can I determine why the `onFailure()` is triggered? I tried `caught.getCause()` but it doesn't return anything.

```java
feedbackService.saveFeedback(email,studentName,usedTemplates,
    new AsyncCallback<String>() {

    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // Show the RPC error message to the user
        caught.getCause();
        Window.alert("Failure!");
    }

    public void onSuccess(String result) {
        Window.alert("Saved!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwable instance is instance of an Exception. You can check if it is a custom Exception like this:

```
if (caught instanceOf CustomException){
```

or if you want to show the message of exception you can use the getMessage():

```
Window.alert("Failure: " + caught.getMessage());
```

Comment: Thank you for the responds. I did it what you suggested and the respond was "null". Any ideas what does this mean?

Comment: I think the best way is to trace your server code. It seems that your server code encounter some exception. Exceptions often are not sent to the client side, instead only onFailure method is fired.

Comment: I agree with @H.Aghassi. This is probably best approached by tracing the server code to see why you're getting a null. Is it the caught object or the message that is null?

Answer (score 0):

GWT-rpc is not not easy to ebug if an error occurs.

The easiest part is th check if the Exception is part of `StatusCodeException`.

- A Statuscode of 404 means, you are pointing to a wrong endpoint
- 0 means, that

  - The searver is unreachable
  - You don't have permissions to check, if the server is available (X-domain-request)

You can use the Chrome-Web-Inspector to bedug GWT-RPC

You should be able to see all calls from the browser to you backend.

The most common failures are because of serialization of object. You have to ensure, that all dtransferred object implement `java.io.Serializable`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it will just be a server side exception being raised which fires the `onFailure()` method.

Try putting breakpoints on your server side. That should help you pinpoint what's going wrong.